# In Android 2.2 how can I remove

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to do some function in Android 2.2. 
How can I remove and the borders in white and gray that is shown in below picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set Activity's theme to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`, in manifest

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your manifest file where you have declared your activity.

```
<activity
 android:name=".activityName"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

or progrmatically you can do it by adding

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

this above line with `onCreate` method

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // put that line in your oncreate method
    setContentView(R.layout.youlayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to have an edit in manifest as follows

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

this line will not show tiltlebar and will be a fullscreen however if you wants to hide just the title bar than use

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

by means yours manifest should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="example.android.some"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

</manifest>
```

you can acieve the same by programming as follows

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: please raise the answer that it will be useful for others as well!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways

1) Programatically :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

2) Modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```